# Delphi TPageControl Set tab width only for one tabsheet

Tags: delphi

The TabWidth property of TPageControl sets width of tab for all pages. Is it possible to set TabWidth property only for one tabsheet?

Answer (score 3):

No. As [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl.TabWidth), your options are:

- Set it to 0 to have the width of each tab automatically calculated, in which case you can have some flexibility using, e.g., spaces on certain tabs to make them wider.
- Set it to a number that will be used as the width of all tabs.